# Varchar value not passing into SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, varchar

Following is my code to call my stored procedure:

```
SqlCommand commandSql = new SqlCommand("GetbyProgramID")

commandSql.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

//commandSql.Parameters.Add("@program_id", SqlDbType.VarChar, 5, programID);
commandSql.Parameters.Add("@program_id", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 5).Value = programID;

SqlParameter returnValue = new SqlParameter("@result", SqlDbType.Int);
returnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
commandSql.Parameters.Add(returnValue);

DBAccessHelper.Execute(commandSql);

var result = returnValue.Value != System.DBNull.Value ? returnValue.Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
return result;
```

And here is my stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetbyProgramID]
       @program_id  varchar,
       @result int OUTPUT 
AS 
BEGIN 
    SELECT @result = system_id 
    FROM dbo.agency_mapping 
    WHERE program_id = @program_id  

    RETURN
END
```

I always get an empty values as the result in my C# code.

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

The values I pass are correct.

Missing anything important ?

Comment: Make sure you are passing the correct `program_id`, also use profiler to see what is actually being sent to your proc and try executing it directly in management studio.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetbyProgramID]
       @program_id  varchar,
       @result int OUTPUT
```

this means that your stored procedure receives a parameter named @program_id with size of 1 char. Probably your SELECT fails for this reason.

Try instead to declare

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetbyProgramID]
       @program_id  varchar(5),
       @result int OUTPUT
```

as from your C# code.
Do not remove the size in the C# code because it is useful to let the Sql Server Engine prepare an optimization plan that can be reused if you call your query a second time.

Mode info here: [How Data Access code Affects Database Performances](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Change your SP as

```
 @program_id  varchar(5)
```

**Edit**: Based on [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1197518/steve) answer, I have updated that removing parameter size.